# On the domains of fractional powers of a selfadjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $T$ be an unbounded selfadjoint positive operator on an Hilbert space ( say $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ ). By Borel functional calculus, i can define the powers $T^r$ for r>0. Suppose that i know the action of $T^r$ on a generic element of its domain, and that this action can be extended to a generic $L^2$ function (taking value in the space of tempered distribution). I still call this map $T^r$ (improperly). Is it true that
$$f\in L^2, T^rf\in L^2\Rightarrow f\in\mathcal{D}(T^r)$$

Comment: I think that the answer is affirmative, and it is a consequence of the spectral theorem (or of the functional calculus). Try to look in some book on the subject

Comment: The general theorem should go along those lines: the domain of the operator $F(T)$ consists of those vectors $\psi \in \mathfrak H$ such that $\int |f(\lambda)|^2\, \mu_\psi(d\lambda)<\infty$, where $\mu_\psi$ is the spectral measure of $T$ associated to $\psi$ (or something like that, I don't remember the precise terminology, sorry). Alternatively, if $T$ is unitarily equivalent to the multiplication by $t$ through the adapted Fourier transform $\mathcal F$, then the domain of $f(T)$ consists of those $\psi\in \mathfrak H$ such that $\|f(t(\xi))\mathcal F \psi\|_{L^2(d\xi)}<\infty$.

Comment: In any case, the philosophy of those theorems is precisely the one you sketch here: the domain of $f(T)$ consists precisely of those vectors to which any reasonable definition of $f(T)$ can be meaningfully applied.

Comment: What does $T^rf \notin L^2$ mean?